# Rubyのstoreに関する疑問、ハッシュテーブルに値が追加されない

Tags: ruby

始めて投稿させていただきます。至らぬところはあるかもしれませんが、どうかお手やわらかにお願い致します。

さて、本題ですが、ひょんな事からRubyのハッシュテーブルで、Twitterユーザを番号で管理する必要に迫られまして、ユーザーの追加と、番号を指定して関連付けられたユーザー名を呼び出すプログラムを作る必要が出てきました。以下がその途中スケッチです。

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
number = ARGV[0],user_name = ARGV[1]

h = {}

h.store(number, user_name)
```

このコードは ./usersnumber.rb 00-00 古池 と言う形で実行し、空のハッシュテールにナンバーとユーザー名が追加されることを期待していましたが、スクリプトを確認したところテーブルに変更はなされていませんでした。伺いたい事をリストアップすると

- ハッシュテーブルhへ破壊的にナンバーとユーザ名を追加したい
- この書き方より賢い書き方はあるのか？

この2つです。不慣れですが、どうかよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 書き間違えられたのかもしれませんが、`number = ARGV[0],user_name = ARGV[1]` という書き方をしますと、`user_name = ARGV[1]` と `number = ARGV[0],user_name` を実行した事になってしまいます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございま。実はつい数ヶ月前にやっとRubyの読み方を身につけたレベルなので"書く"に関しましてはまったくのド素人です。いわばぶっつけ本番で書いている状態なので、どのように修正すれば良いのかわかりません。差し支えなければご教示頂けると幸いです。

Comment: おそらく `number = ARGV[0]` と `user_name = ARGV[1]` とするのだと思いますが、この場合、変数 number は文字列になります。int 型に変換するのであれば、`number = ARGV[0].to_i` としますが、ARGV[0] が数値を表す文字列ではない場合には `0`、小数点数の場合は切り捨て後の整数値に変換されてしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(コメントできないので解答欄で)

質問された書き方だと number は `["00-00", "古池"]` となり、user_name は `"古池"` で、h は `{["00-00", "古池"]=>"古池"}` となります。

修正するなら `,` を `;` に変更して以下のようにすればよいかと。なお number は整数に変換してません。

```
number = ARGV[0];user_name = ARGV[1]
```

これで number は `"00-00"` となり、user_name は `"古池"` となり、h は `{"00-00"=>"古池"}` となります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。提示された方法で正常に動くことを確認しましたが、一つだけ疑問があります。irb usersnumber.rb 00-00 古池 と実行してデバッカーで追ってみた限りではハッシュに値が追加されいるようですが、ソースを見てみると h に値は追加され礼ませんでした。スクリプト自体に恒常的に書き込むにはどのような方法をとればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 遅れました。「スクリプト自体に恒常的に書き込む」というのは、たとえば `./usersnumber.rb 00-00 古池` と実行したあとに `./usersnumber.rb` を実行すると、h に `{"00-00" => "古池"}` がすでに格納されている状態にしたい。という意味でしょうか？ それであれば、h の中身をファイルへ書き出し、次の実行時にはそのファイルから読み込む、という実装が必要です。手段としては YAML 等を使うテがあります https://magazine.rubyist.net/articles/0010/0010-YAML.html